A very basic autosegmental tree using forest
I need to draw a simple autosegmental diagram where the parent node (the feature name) branches into two children (segments), with the ability to control which of the branches are vertical. For example, I would like to be able to produce both of the following:

As far as I can tell, "anchor" is the parameter to manipulate here. But I cannot understand from the documentation how to set it to achieve the desired behavior. I get all sorts of wonky alignments and never a simple vertical line. (I used to use xyling for this, which was clunky but worked, and it is now obsolete.)
What I've tried:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[lab,anchor=west [m] [p, anchor=west]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}


(FWIW I have tried every other combination of anchor specs, with south, east, etc. set for each node.)
This gets me close, but the branch for 'p' is slightly tilted, and the [m] and [p] are not horizontally aligned. Also, the minute I change "lab" to "labial", the branches are both drunk. I understand this is because the positioning is relative to the text of the node labels, but is there no way to do this without micromanaging the precise positioning each time I draw a simple tree?

See How to get limited multidominance in a forest tree for some ideas. This doesn't address the direct issue though, but might be adaptable.  But please don't post code fragments. Instead edit you question to show a compilable document that shows what you're doing.

Here are two ways to do some of what you want. You can specify specific anchor positions for the parent anchor of the feature node. This works reasonably well for medium sized nodes, but not for small nodes.
Alternatively, you could use the calign parameter to align the first or last daughter node. This is more adaptable, but doesn't shift the point of attachment to the left or the right of the parent. I'm assuming the goal of this format is to show an association, in which case the second format should work pretty well, (but I'm not a phonologist).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ft}{m}{[#1]}
\forestset{l assoc/.style = {parent anchor=-45},
           r assoc/.style = {parent anchor=-135},
           L assoc/.style = {calign=last},
           R assoc/.style = {calign=first}
}
\begin{forest}
[\ft{Labial},r assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
[\ft{Labial},l assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
[\ft{Continuant},r assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
[\ft{Lab},r assoc,
    [m, ] [a ]
]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
[\ft{Labial},r assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
[\ft{Labial},L assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
[\ft{Continuant},R assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
[\ft{Lab},R assoc,
    [m, ] [a ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}



Calign is perfect, exactly what I needed. Thanks! Yes, the vertical line shows the original host of the feature in this notation--a kind of head-dependent relationship. In my first tree, labial place spread from [p] to [m], as opposed to the other way around. In the second mini-tree, nasality spreads from the [m] to the vowel.

If you align with child edge rather than child, then you can alter the point of attachment and maintain the vertical edges. (Examples below.)

This is a modification of Alan Munn's answer, which demonstrates a way to shift the feature node's parent anchor left or right, while maintaining vertical edges. This may be useful for either symbolic or practical purposes, since some choices allow trees to be typeset more compactly than with a central anchor.
This uses child edge rather than child for calign. The difference is that the former aligns the parent's parent anchor with the child's child anchor, whereas the latter aligns their anchors. This allows us to keep the edges vertical while shifting the position of the parent's parent anchor.
The parent anchor is the point on the parent node the edge is drawn from. The child anchor is the point on the child node the edge is drawn to. The anchor is the regular tikz anchor.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage[hscale=0.9,a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721702/ addaswyd o ateb Alan Munn: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721700/
\NewDocumentCommand{\ft}{m}{[#1]}
\forestset{
  ll assoc/.style = {parent anchor=-135,for last={calign with current edge}},
  rr assoc/.style = {parent anchor=-45,for first={calign with current edge}},
  lr assoc/.style = {parent anchor=-45,for last={calign with current edge}},
  rl assoc/.style = {parent anchor=-135,for first={calign with current edge}},
  lc assoc/.style = {for last={calign with current edge}},
  rc assoc/.style = {for first={calign with current edge}},
}


\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},rc assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},lc assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Continuant},rc assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Lab},rc assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},rc assoc
    [marginally, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},lc assoc
    [marginally, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},rc assoc
    [m ] [astrophysicist ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},lc assoc
    [m, ] [astrophysicist ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},rl assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},lr assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Continuant},rl assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Lab},rl assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},rl assoc
    [marginally, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},lr assoc
    [marginally, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},rl assoc
    [m ] [astrophysicist ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},lr assoc
    [m, ] [astrophysicist ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},rr assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},ll assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Continuant},rr assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Lab},rr assoc
    [m, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},rr assoc
    [marginally, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},ll assoc
    [marginally, ] [a ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},rr assoc
    [m ] [astrophysicist ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [\ft{Labial},ll assoc
    [m, ] [astrophysicist ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}



I will always bow to your superior forest wisdom. :)

@AlanMunn You shouldn't: it's only a tweak.
